# MIPS srl by a variable

Tags: assembly, mips, mips32

I've done some searching but can't seem to find the answer. Most likely because I'm not really sure how to word it.

if I have the following code

```
for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    x = y >> i
    ...
}
```

is there a way to implement the y >> i instruction without a another loop?

I know this doesn't work, but say the value of i was stored in $s1, doing something this

```
srl $t3, $s5, $s1
```

as opposed to having to setting $t3 to the value of $s5 and then looping through this statement i times

```
srl $t3, $t3, 1
```

Hopefully that makes sense.

Basically I want y * 2^-i each time through the for loop.

Thanks for any help, or even just some beratement about how this is a dup question and I can read that full of shame and get an answer.

Comment: Use `srlv`. Now go read the manual full of shame :D

Comment: omg, thank you! In my defense that's not in my book nor on the reference card of commands that came with the book! I do feel pretty dumb and full of shame tho, lol

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The *MIPS32™ Architecture For Programmers
Volume II: The MIPS32™ Instruction Set* lists the following shift instructions:

- `SLL` Shift Word Left Logical
- `SLLV` Shift Word Left Logical Variable
- `SRA` Shift Word Right Arithmetic
- `SRAV` Shift Word Right Arithmetic Variable
- `SRL` Shift Word Right Logical
- `SRLV` Shift Word Right Logical Variable

The ones of interest to you are the ones with *Variable* in their names, and they work as follows:

```
SLLV rd, rt, rs :  rd ← rt << rs
SRAV rd, rt, rs :  rd ← rt >> rs (arithmetic)
SRLV rd, rt, rs :  rd ← rt >> rs (logical)
```

Only the low-order 5 bits of `rs` are used, giving you shift amounts in the range 0-31.